# How to split string before and after any character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could I split a string before any character and after **any** character. E.g:

```
x = '846a12'
```

How would I output:

```
z = ['846','a','12']
```

The problem in this case is I have mentioned specific character in my function (specific character: 'a' in above example). If input is different character(Let's say: 'b') my function fails. How can I deal with random characters?

Thanks.

Comment: `'846a12'.partition('a')`?

Comment: What does your example have to do with "any character"? Should the example be something like '846a12b55' turned into ['846','a','12','b','55']? You should properly show the general case you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools` for solving these types of problems, for the cases where there are more than one occurrence of the separator, e.g.:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [''.join(x) for _, x in it.groupby('846a12', key=lambda c: c=='a')]
['846', 'a', '12']
```

Comment: Really? This is a terrible solution compared to either of the other two solutions in the comments. It's much less readable, and I would be willing to bet it's less efficient as well.

Comment: Agree, if there is only one occurrence of the separator, and I'm not sure it is that terrible compared to the `re` based solutions.

Comment: Nope, the linked dupe takes care of multiple occurrences of the separator.